Any variable that contains unique request_id or anything similar?
In Squid config, is there any variable - %VAR - that contains the current unique request id or anything similar?
I'll need to pass that into an external script, for instance:
# squi.conf
auth_param basic program %REQUEST_ID(???) /etc/squid/my_auth.py

This may not be an authentication script, this is just an example.
I've searched but haven't found anything about it.
